# Springboot service unable to recover after database failover

Tags: spring-boot, recover, bitronix

We have a springboot service which has the capability to recover itself after database restart. But all of a sudden we noticed "recoverer is already running, abandoning this recovery request" in the logs and healthcheck of service is failed. We had to get the service restarted in both our datacenters.

Has anybody faced the similar issue?

==Edit
Below are the configurations:

```
spring.jta.log-dir=target/transaction-logs
spring.jta.bitronix.datasource.className=bitronix.tm.resource.jdbc.lrc.LrcXADataSource
spring.jta.bitronix.datasource.driverProperties.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jta.bitronix.datasource.driverProperties.url=
spring.jta.bitronix.datasource.driverProperties.user=
spring.jta.bitronix.datasource.driverProperties.password=
spring.jta.bitronix.datasource.test-query=select 1
spring.jta.bitronix.datasource.max-pool-size=100
spring.jta.bitronix.datasource.prepared-statement-cache-size=100
```

Comment: Could you provide more detail about how the recovery sequence is triggered? We don't have enough information to process here. It may be caused by multiple requests triggered when the database is restarted or your service did not shut down properly after the database reset or anything in between.

Comment: I am not much aware about what is going on in application as I am new to it but here are the configurations that I could see